# How does this Java code which determines whether a String contains all unique characters work?

Tags: java, operators

I have a program which I found online which basically tells whether the `String` contains all unique characters, below is the code

```
private static boolean areCharsUnique(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 256)
            return false;
        int checker = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            checker |= (1 << val);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am baffled by this line of code `if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)` and also

`checker |= (1 << val);`

I know that `<<` is a left shift operator, but how exactly left shifting helps in the above situation?

**In short how does the above program work?**

Comment: I'm hoping, for your sake, this is an exercise or example rather than production code. :)

Comment: @Palpatim I am trying to learn the concept of bit shifting so yes the above code is an exercise:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code works under the assumption that ASCII character set has consecutive character in its mapping so that `a == 97, b == 98`, and so on.

Starting from this you can calculate a delta distance from the `a` character, eg `'e' - 'a' = 5`. This distance is used to set (through `checker |= (1 << val)`) a bit in a integer number (which has 32 bits).

So if a `'e'` character is found then bit at index 5 is set to 1 for `checker`.

This is done for every char by ensuring that you never find a bit that has been already set previously (through `if (checker & (1 << val)) > 0)`).

This works only for lowercase characters (even because int has 32 bits). An `HashSet<Character>` would be surely better.

Comment: Actually, a `BitSet` would serve as a perfect generalization of this approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: it may work but you will probably have to adjust it according to the character encoding you are using.

Comment: There is no encoding to Java strings. Or, if you like, there's only one encoding to them.

Answer (score 2):

Each character is converted to a numeric index from 0 (== 'a') to 26 (== 'z') and beyond. For each of those indexes, the corresponding bit in an integer value (== 'checker') is set. If the bit for that index is already set, you can determine that that character already was contained in the given string.

Note that this algorithm only works for lowercase strings, as for the uppercase characters, the value will overflow and give unreliable results. One fix for this would be to convert the 'checker' type from int to long.

Answer (score 2):

We convert each character to a numeric index from 0 ('a') to 25 ('z') here

```
 int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

Here we look at binary presentation of `checker`
for example, if `checker = 001`
this means we already have char 'a' counted, because first bit is set to 1.

In this row we check if bit related to current letter is set. `1<<val` represent `00100..00`, where `1` is set in `val`-th position from left. Others digits are zeros. About binary operation you may read [at TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation)

```
if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {...}
```

This line `checker |= (1 << val);` set bit at position `val` from left to `1` in `checker`.

**EDIT:**
Here you may assume `checker` like `bool arr[32]`,

and

`int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';` the same as `if(arr[str.charAt(i) - 'a'] == true) ...`

and
`checker |= (1 << val);` is equal to `arr[val] = true`.

So, at begging you have all elements of `arr` set to zeros.
`val` - is integer representation of letters from 'a' to 'z'.

Answer (score 1):

This code store the presence of each lowercase character as a single bit in a 32-bit integer.

`1 << val` computes a number with only that bit set.

Comment: I tried debugging that piece of code, the value of both checker and val change after every i'th step, so where exactly is the presence of lowercase character stored?

Comment: It's stored as a bitmap, where each bit represents a character offset from ASCII 'a'. So, rather than the literal character "b", being stored, the program sets the 2nd bit of @checker@ to 1. Think of it as similar to a substitution cipher, where a=0, b=1, c=2, etc. As others have pointed out, though, this solution is unworkable for anything other than a limited range of ASCII lowercase characters.

Comment: yes I am aware of that, thank you very much for this vivid explanation.