# Scala: Function test a string for unique char

Tags: java, scala

Solved! Solution at the bottom.

I'm porting some Java code to Scala for fun and I trapped into a pretty nifty way of bit-shifting in Java. The Java code below takes a String as input and tests if it consists of unique characters.

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
if (str.length() > 256)return false; }
int checker = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
  if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
 checker |= (1 << val);
 }
return true;
```

Full listing is here: https://github.com/marvin-hansen/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%201/Question1_1/Question.java

How the code exactly works is explained here:
[How does this Java code which determines whether a String contains all unique characters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324947/how-does-this-java-code-which-determines-whether-a-string-contains-all-unique-ch)

Porting this directly to Scala doesn't really work so I'm looking for a more functional way to re-write the stuff above.

I have tried BigInt & BitSet

```
def isUniqueChars2(str : String) : Boolean =
// Java, char's are Unicode so there are 32768 values
if (str.length() > 32768)  false
val checker = BigInt(1)
 for(i <- 0 to str.length){
   val value = str.charAt(i)
   if(checker.testBit(value)) false
   checker.setBit(value)
 }
true
}
```

This works, however, but without bit-shifting and without lowercase assumption.
Performance is rather unknown ....

However, I would like to do a more functional style solution.

Thanks to user3189923 for the solution.

```
 def isUniqueChars(str : String) = str.distinct == str
```

That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.distinct == str
```

In general, method `distinct` preserves order of occurrence after removing duplicates. Consider

```
implicit class RichUnique(val str: String) extends AnyVal {
  def isUniqueChars() = str.distinct == str
}
```

and so

```
"abc".isUniqueChars
res: Boolean = true

"abcc".isUniqueChars
res: Boolean = false
```

Comment: was just going to ask. Thanks for the good idea, I wasn't aware of distinct

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
str.toSet.size == str.size
```

?