# Implement an algorithm in Scala to determin if a string has all unique characters

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am solving trivial problems to learn Scala. Here is what I have come up with

```
def isUnique(str: String): Boolean = {
    if (str.length > 128) return false
    val uniqueChars = new Array[Boolean](128)

    !(str.map(c => addChar(c, uniqueChars)).find(identity).isDefined)
}

def addChar(ch: Char, uniqueChars: Array[Boolean]): Boolean = {
    if (uniqueChars(ch)) return true else {
    uniqueChars(ch) = true;
    return false
}
```

Is that it?

Please note that I don't care about the logic or optimization at this point. I only need to learn the Scala way of doing it.

[Edit]
Let's assume we don't want to use the string distinct method. I only need to verify the functional style of Scala.

Comment: `str.length == str.distinct.length`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834018/scala-function-test-a-string-for-unique-char

Comment: Oops! This is even more direct: `str == str.distinct`

Comment: @jwvh Thanks... I wasn't aware of this method. Can you see my edit in the question? Lets assume we don't want to use distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so if you don't to want utilize the `distinct` library method then recursion is usually the functional way to go.

```
def isUnique(str: String, chrs: Set[Char] = Set()): Boolean =
  str.length == 0 ||
    !chrs(str.head) &&
      isUnique(str.tail, chrs + str.head)

isUnique("abcdexf")  // true
isUnique("abcdxxf")  // false
isUnique("fbcdexf")  // false
isUnique("abdbexf")  // false
```

Comment: Pretty slick! It took a min to get my head around this though. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using sets, why not use `str.toSet.size == str.size` ?

Comment: @RomainG; Since `distinct` had been rejected, and "functional style" requested, I thought that a demonstration of early termination via recursion might be what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

You want to "learn scala way of doing it", by actually doing it in a way, that makes no sense to use in scala? Scala way of doing it `str == str.distinct`. If "you don't want to use `distinct`", then `str.toSet.size == str.length`. If you don't want `toSet` either, then `str.groupBy(identity).values.map(_.size).forall(_ == 1)`.
If you don't want `.groupBy` then 
`str.sorted.sliding(2).forall(s => s.head != s.last)`

Etc. ... At some point, "scala way" just stops being "scala way" and becomes a java program written in scala syntax.

Comment: I don't want to make it Java. I wanted to know how would you implement distinct method in Scala. I am sure its not implemented using Java or groupBy or sorting. Please also see the accepted answer above. (FYI, I didn't down vote your answer).